# How do you refresh a JSON file without re-compling the angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently displaying information from a JSON file I am saving in my assets folder. It is then being displayed as a table. As of now the JSON file is only loaded when the angular application is built. I would like to dynamically load this file so it can be loaded, or deleted even when the app is built.

The file I would like to dynamically pull from is located in 'src/assets/data/'

This is how I'm pulling the JSON file:

export let MyData: MYDATA[] = require ('src/assets/data/MyJSON.JSON');

In the end I would like to be able to update or delete that JSON file in the assets folder, which would then update that MyData variable and the table, so I wont have to keep on running ng build anytime that JSON file changes.

Comment: I can provide an answer for the first part but as far as saving updated JSON goes I'm not sure that's a good way to approach. You should make that type of updating an API endpoint/DB store. Or local storage if it's user specific but not saving a JSON file.

Comment: You can always use `fetch()` to load the JSON any time you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to check json file changed.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   MYDATA = require ('src/assets/data/MyJSON.JSON');
}, 5000); //check 5 seconds
```